# Angular 7 - PrimeNg 7 views doesn't render until window resize

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working in an angular app that was correctly working with Angular 5 and PrimeNg 5.

After migration to Angular 7 and PrimeNg 7 I have an issue in every views: just renders some basics HTML elements but doesn't render any primeng related component, and it renders completely just after resizing the window.

Does anybody have any similar issue? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've keep trying find a solution and now I can provide some code just in case someone can help, (because I found that using **setTimeout** at last instruction on ngOnInit it solves the issue):

I have an app.component in which everything works as expected, and I can load primeNg components with getting the issue.

The app starts in a login screen where I can also load primeNg components without problem. And after this login we get to the home where I have perfectly rendered elements, including the primeNg ones.

The bug appears in the first custom component on that page, that contains primeNg components, where I find the problem in the first place.

The strange thing is that I managed to solve it by wrapping the last ngOnInit statement of that component in a timeout of 0 seconds.

HOME.COMPONENT.HMTL

```html
    <div id="main-menu" class="menu360"  #launcher *ngIf="(isOpen || isHome()) && viewLoaded">
    <mat-card class="cs-card-padding" class="menu360-card">
        <div class="ui-row-fluid ui-row-fluid-top full-width">
            <div class="ui-col-fluid menu360-panel">
                <div class="ui-row-fluid">
                    <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let menu of filterEnabledItems()" class="ui-col-fluid ui-col-fluid-4 ui-col-fluid-xs-2 ui-col-fluid-md-3">
                        <a class="menu360-list" mat-list-item (click)="onCloseMenu(menu)" role="listitem" *ngIf="menu.action!=null" [routerLink]="[menu.action]" [pTooltip]="menu.texto" [tooltipDisabled]="disableTooltip">
                            <div class="menu360-item {{ menu.icon ? 'menu360-icon-' + menu.icon : '' }}" [ngClass]="{'menu360-icon': menu.icon}"></div>
                            <span class="menu360-label">{{menu.texto}}</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="menu360-list" mat-list-item (click)="menuChange(menu)" role="listitem" *ngIf="menu.action==null" [pTooltip]="menu.texto" [tooltipDisabled]="disableTooltip">
                            <div class="menu360-item {{ menu.icon ? 'menu360-icon-' + menu.icon : '' }}" [ngClass]="{'menu360-icon': menu.icon}">
                                <div *ngIf="menu.parentList" class="menu360-back"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="menu360-label" [ngClass]="menu.parentList ? 'back-label' : ''">{{menu.texto}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </mat-list>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-col-fluid  menu360-overview">
                <div class="ui-col-fluid center menu360-action" (click)="toggleOverview()">
                    <svg *ngIf="!isExpanded" width="76px" height="82px" viewBox="0 0 76 82" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="arrow-left" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            "svg path..."
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <svg *ngIf="isExpanded" width="76px" height="82px" viewBox="0 0 76 82" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="arrow-right" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            "svg path ..."
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <dashboard *ngIf="overview === 'dashboard'" [isExpanded]="isExpanded"></dashboard>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

HOME.COMPONENT.TS

```js
    @Component({selector: 'home', templateUrl: './home.component.html'})

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() isOpen: boolean;
        @Input() newStatusLauncher: any;
        @Output() closeMenu: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
        @Output() sendBreadcrumb = new EventEmitter();

        floatMenu = [];
        defaultMenu = [];
        isExpanded = false;
        overview: string;
       disableTooltip = true;
       viewLoaded = false;

       @ViewChild('launcher') launcher;

       constructor(private router: Router,
                private _MenuProviderService: MenuService,
                private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.reset();
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initMenu();
    }

    initMenu() {
        const sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionId');
        const request: MenuRq = new MenuRq(sessionId, GlobalService.getPARAMS());

        this._MenuProviderService.obtenMenu(request).subscribe((menu) => {
            this.defaultMenu = menu;
            this.setMainMenu();
        });
    }

    isHome() {
        return this.router.url === '/home';
    }

    setMainMenu() {
        this.floatMenu = this.cloneArray(this.defaultMenu);
        this.overview = 'dashboard';
        this.viewLoaded = true;
    }

    cloneArray(data) {
        return data.map((element) => Object.assign({}, element));
    }

    refresh() {
        this._applicationRef.tick();
    }

    onToggleMenu(isOpen) {
        this.isOpen = typeof(isOpen) === 'boolean' ? isOpen : !this.isOpen;
    }

    onCloseMenu(menu) {
        this.onToggleMenu(false);
        this.closeMenu.emit(this.isOpen);
        this.sendBreadcrumb.emit({label: menu.texto, isActive: true});
        this.isExpanded = false;
    }

    menuChange(menuChange) {
        const submenus = menuChange.submenus;

        if (submenus && submenus.length > 0) {
            this.getActionSubmenu(menuChange.submenus, menuChange.texto);
        } else if (menuChange.parentList) {
            this.getActionGoBack(menuChange.parentList, menuChange.texto);
        }
        this.getOverview();
    }

    getActionSubmenu(submenus, label) {
        if (submenus && submenus.length > 0) {
            this.getGoBackOptionMenu(submenus);
            this.floatMenu = submenus;
            this.sendBreadcrumb.emit({
                label: label,
                floatMenu: submenus,
                isActive: true
            });
        }
    }

    getOverview() {
        const item = this.floatMenu.filter(menu => menu.overview);

        if (item.length > 0) {
            this.overview = item[0].overview;
        }
    }

    getActionGoBack(parentList, label) {
        this.floatMenu = parentList;
        this.sendBreadcrumb.emit({
            label: label,
            parentList: parentList,
            isActive: false
        });
    }

    getGoBackOptionMenu(list) {
        if (list[0].id !== 'go_back') {
            list.unshift({
                enabled: true,
                parentList: this.cloneArray(this.floatMenu),
                id: 'go_back',
                texto: 'Volver'
            });
        }
    }

    filterEnabledItems() {
        return this.floatMenu.filter(x => x.enabled);
    }

    toggleOverview() {
        this.launcher.nativeElement.classList.toggle('menu360-expanded');
        this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
        this.disableTooltip = !this.disableTooltip;
    }

    reset() {
        this.isExpanded = false;
    }
    }
```

DASHBOARD.COMPONENT.HTML

```html
    <div class="layout-main dashboard">
    <div class="card-form-title">
        Overview Reservas BP - {{fechaHoy | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}
    </div>
    <div class="ui-row-fluid">
        <div class="ui-col-fluid {{ isExpanded ? 'ui-col-fluid-6 ui-col-fluid-sm-4 ui-col-fluid-md-3' : 'ui-col-fluid-6' }}">
            <label class="white-label">Hoteles seleccionados:</label>
            <gp-multiselect styleClass="full-width"
                                                [selectionLabel]="'Hoteles seleccionados'"
                                                defaultLabel="Todos los hoteles"
                                                [options]="hoteles.options"
                                                [(ngModel)]="hoteles.selection"></gp-multiselect>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-col-fluid {{ isExpanded ? 'ui-col-fluid-6 ui-col-fluid-sm-4 ui-col-fluid-md-2 ui-col-fluid-lg-1' : 'ui-col-fluid-6 ui-col-fluid-sm-3 ui-col-fluid-lg-2' }}">
            <button type="button" class="full-width ui-button-low-padded" label="Buscar" pButton icon="fa fa-search" (click)="filtrar()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-separation-lg tabview-wrapper">
        <p-tabView #dashboard class="tabview-form tabview-menu">
            <p-tabPanel header="Gráfico">
                <div class="ui-row-fluid dashboard-kpi-group-separation">
                    <div class="ui-col-fluid ui-col-fluid-narrow {{ isExpanded ? 'ui-col-fluid-6' : 'ui-col-fluid-12' }}">
                        <dashboard-grafico360 #chart1 class="full-width" [(titulo)]="tituloHoy" [data]="metricasHoy"
                            (filter)="setFiltrosHoy($event)"></dashboard-grafico360>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!isExpanded" class="card-separator full-width"></div>
                    <div class="ui-col-fluid ui-col-fluid-narrow {{ isExpanded ? 'ui-col-fluid-6' : 'ui-col-fluid-12' }}">
                        <dashboard-grafico360 #chart2 class="full-width" [(titulo)]="tituloMes" [data]="metricasMes"
                            [fechaDesde]="fechppaDiaUno" [fechaHasta]="fechaAyer" (filter)="setFiltrosMes($event)"></dashboard-grafico360>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
        </p-tabView>
    </div>
</div>
```

DASHBOARD.COMPONENT.TS

```js
    import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {GetHotelesRq, HotelService} from '@shared/services/hotel.service';
    import {GPSelector} from 'gp-all-component';
    import {
      GetGraficoFechasRq,
      GetGraficoOverviewRq,
      GraficoOverview,
      OverviewService
    } from '@shared/services/overview.service';
    import moment from 'moment';
    import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
    import {GpBaseComponent} from 'gp-all-component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'dashboard',
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
      providers: [HotelService, OverviewService]
    })

    export class Dashboard360Component extends GpBaseComponent implements 
    OnInit, OnDestroy {
      @ViewChild('chart1') chart1;
      @ViewChild('chart2') chart2;
      @Input() isExpanded: boolean;

      metricasHoy: any;
      metricasMes: any;
      metricasFecha: any;
      ...
      "every variable declarations..."
      ...
  
      constructor(private _hotelService: HotelService,
              private _overviewService: OverviewService) {
         super();

         this.dataObservable.subscribe(value => {
            if (!this.dataGraficoTotal) {
                this.dataGraficoTotal = value;
            } else {
                this.metricasFecha = this.convertToGraficoPorFecha(this.dataGraficoTotal.concat(value));
        this.chart3.cargarDatos(this.metricasFecha);
        this.dataGraficoTotal = null;
      }
    });
  }

     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.fechaDiaUno = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
        if (moment().isSame(moment(this.fechaDiaUno), 'day')) {
           this.fechaAyer = this.fechaHoy;
        } else {
           this.fechaAyer = moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate();
        }
        const dias = moment().diff(moment(this.fechaDiaUno), 'days');
        this.tituloMes = (dias === 1 ? 'Último ' : 'Últimos ' + dias) + ((dias === 1) ? ' Día' : ' Días');
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.populateHoteles();
        }, 0);
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
         this.cacheKeys.forEach(key => {
            sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
         });
         this.dataObservable.unsubscribe();
      }

      emitData(val) {
         this.dataObservable.next(val);
      }

      populateHoteles() {
         const rq = new GetHotelesRq('CRM');
         this._hotelService.getHoteles(rq).subscribe(data => {
         if (data.ok) {
          this.hoteles.cargarDatos(data.hoteles, 'codigo', ['codigo', 'nombre'], null, null, true);
          this.filtrar();
        } else if (data.error != null && data.error.errorMessage != null) {
          this.showErrorAlert(data.error.errorMessage);
          console.error(data.error.internalErrorMessage);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
    }
```

As you can see I have to wrap this.populateHotels at ngOnInit in a timeout to get to solve the problem. But I imagine that it is not the correct implementation and there must be another better solution that allows me not to have to work with timeout.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: May you provide some code and what error message you are getting? otherwise, How do you we know the problem?

Comment: Thanks for answering @Al-Mothafar, the problem is I don't get any error, so I don't have any hint about what section of code can be responsible of it. The app is tremendously huge. I'm so sorry, I understand that way it's difficult.

Comment: @rmi8092 how do we solve this problem?